# PHP script to download MP3 album art from Google Images

Tags: php, image, google-search, google-image-search

I have a lot of music albums organised into subfolders in the 'My Music' folder in Windows, and finding album art for them is time consuming and cumbersome. I have previously used this little PHP script in my browser to loop through and do a Google Image lookup using the subfolders' names.

```
$folders = glob('*');

foreach($folders as $folder) {
if(!is_dir($folder)) {
    echo "Skipping {$folder}<br>";
    continue;
}

$searchname = str_replace('_',' ',$folder);

ob_flush();
echo "<b>Checking {$searchname}...</b><br>";
flush();

$googleUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=isz:l&q=".urlencode($searchname);
$contents = file_get_contents($googleUrl);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($contents);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $counter;
    $tag = $tag->getAttribute('href');
    $tag = parse_url($tag);
    $tag = $tag['query'];

    if ((strpos($tag, "imgurl") !== false) && ($counter < 5)) {
        $counter++;
        preg_match('~=(.*?)&imgrefurl~', $tag, $output);
        $tag = $output[1];
        $image = file_get_contents($tag);

        echo "Downloading image" . $counter . ".jpg<br>";
        file_put_contents("{$folder}/image" . $counter .".jpg", $image);
    }
}
$counter = 0;
}
```

If I do a var_dump($contents), I can see a Google images DOM after being parsed, but it does not contain any img src links anymore when inspected with Chrome's Dev tools. It now looks visually very different from Google Images' current look.

This got the job done well enough only a couple of months ago, but returning to it now, something broke, maybe because something changed on Google's end.

I am pretty new to coding, so any fixes/comments/alternatives are appreciated to get this working again.

Comment: You should check out the Google custom search API. I think it has access to photo results now.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but as far as I can tell, image results are not yet supported. I could find no mention at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/Samples, which otherwise contains a plethora of information for other Google services.

Comment: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2012/02/image-results-now-available-from-custom.html

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how would I use the custom search API to query Google images? There is a lot of info out there explaining how to do custom searches for your own site, but not how to hook into google.com

Comment: Note that just because it’s on the Internet doesn’t mean you’re allowed to use it.

Comment: What does that have to do with my original question? Are you implying I'm not allowed to use Google Images, or was that a very backward way of saying that the Custom Search API is not public?